# How to redirect to url within same context

Tags: vert.x

I have `/logout` action, that should redirect to `/login`. `/login` renders template, where I read flash message from context. This works, but url in browser is still remains "/logout":

```
router.get("/logout").handler((ctx) => {
  if (ctx.user()!=null) {
    ctx.clearUser()
    //flash message
    ctx.put("msg", "Logout succeed")
  }
  ctx.reroute("/login")
})
```

What I want, but url should be "/login":

[image]

Better to use(?):

```
ctx.response.putHeader("location", "/login").setStatusCode(302).end()
```

But there is different context. So I haven't flash message.

How to redirect to `/login` within same context?

**Upd.**
Question related to this [issue](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/166)

Comment: The [vert.x samples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/search?l=Java&q=setStatusCode%28302%29&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) typically use this approach: `ctx.response.putHeader("location", "/login").setStatusCode(302).end()`.

Comment: Yes, but it's starting new request(another context). I need read conext data in "login" handler written in "logout" handler.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here but the question title is: "How to redirect to url within same context" whereas your later updates (and your last comment) talk about a new context.

Comment: Title - correct. My comment was about your approach: it's starts another context, but i need same. Sorry, maybe my english skills not perfect? :)

Comment: Nah, that was my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with flash messages you should add a cookie to the redirect with the content:

```
// this makes the message available to the client
ctx
  .addCookie(Cookie.cookie("flashMessage", "Logout succeed"));
// configure where to redirect
ctx.response()
  .putHeader("location", "/login");
// perform the redirect
ctx.end(302);
```

Then on the client side you need a bit of JavaScript to read the message and
perform the display as you wish. Since there is no simple way to read cookies on the browser if you're using jQuery with the cookie plugin you can do something like:

```
$.fn.flashMessage = function (options) {
    var target = this;
    options = $.extend({}, options, { timeout: 3000 });
    if (!options.message) {
        options.message = getFlashMessageFromCookie();
        deleteFlashMessageCookie();
    }
    if (options.message) {
        if (typeof options.message === "string") {
            target.html("<span>" + options.message + "</span>");
        } else {
            target.empty().append(options.message);
        }
    }

    if (target.children().length === 0) return;

    target.fadeIn().one("click", function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    if (options.timeout > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () { target.fadeOut(); }, options.timeout);
    }

    return this;

    function getFlashMessageFromCookie() {
        return $.cookie("FlashMessage");
    }

    function deleteFlashMessageCookie() {
        $.cookie("FlashMessage", null, { path: '/' });
    }
};
```

And add a placeholder in your HTML like:

```
<div id="flash-message"></div>
```

And trigger it like:

```
$(function() {
  $("#flash-message").flashMessage();
});
```